# pointer, malloc and char in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, cstring

im trying to copy a const char array to some place in the memory and point to it .

lets say im defining this var under the main prog :

```
char *p = NULL;
```

and sending it to a function with a string :

```
myFunc(&p, "Hello");
```

now i want that at the end of this function the pointer will point to the letter H but if i puts() it, it will print Hello .

here is what i tried to do :

```
void myFunc(char** ptr , const char strng[] ) {
    *ptr=(char *) malloc(sizeof(strng));    
    char * tmp=*ptr;
    int i=0;
    while (1) {
        *ptr[i]=strng[i];
        if (strng[i]=='\0') break;
        i++;
    }
    *ptr=tmp;
}
```

i know its a rubbish now, but i would like to understand how to do it right, my idea was to allocate the needed memory, copy a char and move forward with the pointer, etc..

also i tried to make the ptr argument byreferenec (like &ptr) but with no success due to a problem with the lvalue and rvalue .

the only thing is changeable for me is the function, and i would like not to use strings, but chars as this is and exercise .

thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to use C memory management in C++ ?

Comment: thats the way i want to do it(without using new command), actually the exercise is in C but i only have visual C++ on my PC .

Comment: Then you should tag your question `C`, otherwise you will get `C++` answers.

Comment: Visual C++ will also compile C code - just give your source file a .c suffix instead of .cpp and it will be compiled as C.

Comment: thanks for that comments, changed the tags to C and the file extension.

Comment: if you want to malloc, you also need to pass the length of the string explicitly. So it should be `void myFunc(char** ptr , const char strng[], int length)`. Using `sizeof` may give you wrong result.

Comment: i used strlen within the function instead, thanks .

Answer (score 3):

Just replace all the `char*` with `std::string`. Do that until you have a very specific reason to not use existing utilities, which is something you don't have as a beginner. None of the code above requires `malloc()` or raw pointers.

Some more notes:

- `const char strng[]` as parameter is the same as `const char* strng`. The array syntax doesn't make it an array, it remains a pointer. I don't use this syntax in order to avoid this confusion.
- Use `static_cast` or one of the other C++ casts not the C-style like `(char*)malloc(..)`. The reason is that they are safer.
- Check the return value of `malloc()`, it can return null. Also, you must call `free()` eventually, otherwise your application leaks memory.

Finally, the pointer does point to the 'H', which is just the first element of the string. Output `*p` instead of `p` to see this.

Answer (score 1):

You code work as desired except

```
    *ptr[i]=strng[i];
```

should be

```
    (*ptr)[i]=strng[i];
```

Without the parens, it acts like `*(ptr[i])=strng[i];

2) Also

```
malloc(sizeof(strng));
```

s/b

```
malloc(strlen(strng)+1);
```

You may want to look at `strdup(strng)`.

---

[edit per OP's request]

**difference between** `*(ptr[i])` and `(*ptr)[i]`

```
// OP desired function
(*ptr)[i] = 'x';
// Dereference ptr, getting the address of a char *array.
// Assign 'x' to the i'th element of that char * array.

// OP post with the undesired function
*(ptr[i]) = 'x';
//  This is like
char *q = ptr[i];
*q = 'x';
// This make sense _if_ ptr were an array of char *.  
// Get the i'th char * from ptr and assign to q.  
// Assign 'x' to to the location pointer to by q.
```

Comment: Also recommend checking the malloc result for NULL as it is good programming practice.

Comment: thanks alot !!! can you clarify the difference between *(ptr[i]) and (*ptr)[i]? the first is the value of the memory pointer to but +i places forward and the latter is?

Comment: @user2534078 `(*ptr)[i]` is a pointer to an array of i elements.

Comment: ...but only in a declaration, PHIfounder. In this case, it first evaluates the expression `*ptr` and then applies the `[i]` to it. Since `*ptr` is equivalent to `ptr[0]` here, you get ptr[0][i]. To understand that, remember that `ptr` points to a two-dimensional array, although in the first dimension there is just a single element, a `char*` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is all the code needed...
nothing more...

```
void myFunc(char **pp, char * str){
*pp = str;
```

}

The only issue here is that "Hello" resides in read only section because it is a constant string... so you can't change "Hello" to something else...